# How to populate a list of files when saving a Shiny App as a function

Tags: r, function, shiny

I Would like to save a Shiny App as an R function. Actually I have a list of files which i want in a drop down menu. Without wrapping my Shiny App in a function, i would do it by putting all the files in the directory having `server.r` and `ui.r` , putting the lines

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "data",pattern="\\.csv$")
names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "", filenames)
```

in `ui.r` and then run the App. But here i am wrapping the App in a function. I have no idea how to get the files in this case. I have some example code down here.

```
shinyapp <- function(var) {
  filenames <- list.files(path = "data",pattern="\\.csv$")
  names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "", filenames)
  require(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          h5("Upload Data Files",style="bold"),
          selectInput('dataset',"Choose file", c("Please select a file" ='',filenames)),
          sliderInput("n", "Bins", 5, 100, 20)),

        mainPanel(plotOutput("hist"))

    )), 
    server = function(input, output) {

      output$hist <- renderPlot( 
        hist(var, breaks = input$n,
             col = "skyblue", border = "white") 
      )
    }
)
}
```

I can launch the App by calling the function `shinyapp(iris$Sepal.Length)`. But here the difficulty is how to get the files in dropdown .